# Deactivate Hot spots in CanOe using it's COM interface

Tags: python, com, canoe

my issue is to deactivate a loggingblock in CanOE by using it's COM interface. As programming langugage I'm using Python. I have Access to the LoggingCollection and can set the filename. Now I will deactivate this block, but I can't find a way to do it. Has anyone an idea to do it? In the CanOE help they write About the data flow and hot spots to Control the data.

I have a online Setup.
I guess that I Need to Access a Special object to deactivate teh logging block. The members of the Block itself has no activate/deactivate state.

The Setup is simple as possible. Real Bus to a logging block. All hot spots at the Moment are activated. dbc file is correctly added.

```
self.App = CreateObject('CANoe.Application')
self.logging = self.App.Configuration.OnlineSetup.LoggingCollection(1)
self.logging.FullName = 'Trace_{MeasurementStart}.blf'
if bLoggingActivated == false:
    --> What should I do here?
self.App.Measurement.Start()
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot disable the block itself, but you can disable logging of all events.

This can be done on the `LoggingFilter` object which can be gotten from the `Logging` object.

In your case this would be something like this:

```
self.logging.Filter.Disable(0)
```

`0` means *all events*. Check the CANoe documentation for other values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Now I found a second way. 

It is possible to use the trigger inside of the Logging Block to start and use the Start Stop functions.


Nice to know: It isn't possible to de/ activate the hot spots in the measurement Setup with COM calls (Statement of the Vector Support)